# Cartesian Product in database

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, cartesian-product

I want to create a **cartesian** product of columns of a single table in database.

I have one table with 3 columns and 3 values in each column then I want as 27 resultant rows of cartesian product within the columns of table.

What is the best possible way to get this result or either I should use any data structure to generate my output?

Answer (score 1):

Creating a cartesian product is simple.

```
select 1 as one,2 as two,3 as three
into #test
union all select 4,5,6
union all select 7,8,9

select t1.*
from
  #test t1,
  #test t2,
  #test t3

drop table #test
```

This will self join every record from `test` (instance of t1) to every other record in `test` (instance of t2).

If you want to create a new table, simply change `select t1.*` to `select t1.* into myTableName` and they will populate that table.

EDIT:
Based on your question, I believe that my answer will give you what you want.  It is possible however that you want to [pivot](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) your data.

Comment: thanks for your help....but there is one more scenario as I am making the table in database at runtime and also the insertion in table is also done at run time ...so the number of columns are not fixed. So what will be the solution for this.

Comment: @Neeraj_Yadav If thats the case, why dont you create your table differently?  Get rid of this awful db design and do something more maintainable.

Comment: Post some sample input as well as what you want as a result.

Comment: For example i have one csv file with three columns(Operating System, Browser, Processor) and the values in each column may vary. Now all this work is entered at the time of execution. Importing CSV file and then creating table in database, Inserting the value in table. So i have to develop logic so that it can be applicable to any csv file which will be imported in future with 'n' number of columns and rows and create cartesian product. Using database is mandatory.